# exception while using firebase swift3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am doing such as this example in the link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

but I am getting this exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default FIRDatabase instance. Must call FIRApp.configure() before using FIRDatabase.

I downloaded the final project from the same page and getting the same exception even if I put *GoogleService-Info.plist* and enabled the keychain!

any help is appreciated

Comment: you need to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, the name of firebase app now is `FirebaseApp` instead of `FIRApp` the tutorial is outdated

Comment: Its better if you can share your dummy project.

Comment: @ReinierMelian you are right I used FIRApp like him, but when I use FirebaseApp instead it gives me >> Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'

Comment: did you `import Firebase` ??

Comment: You had firebase integrated with cocoapods or manually?

Comment: @emaso you installed Firebase pod?

Comment: @emaso let me know if solves your issue

Comment: yes I imported it and this is my pod file   

 platform :ios, '9.0'
  use_frameworks!

  target 'Grocr' do
     pod 'Firebase/Core'
     pod 'Firebase/Database'
     pod 'Firebase/Auth'


  end

  
 integrated with cocapods   @ReinierMelian

Comment: @ReinierMelian no I still have the same error : Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'

Comment: @emaso what happen? my answer don't solve your issue?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes it helped...thank you very much, I appreciate your good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, the name of firebase app now is `FirebaseApp` instead of `FIRApp` the tutorial is outdated

and use this pod file content

```
project 'Grocr.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Grocr' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Grocr
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

also you need delete the pod folder and perform a `pod install --verbose`